# How to be notified when IP is up?

Tags: linux, ip, ping

I would like to ping a IP-Adress an want to be notified.

System: Linux Fedora.

Has anybody a idea or a Software?

Comment: `ping -a xx.xx.xx.xx` will start beeping when the IP address starts responding. Is that the sort of thing you're after? Your question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this shell script. Found on http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/unix/shell_scripts/ping

```
#! /bin/sh

# -q quiet
# -c nb of pings to perform

ping -q -c5 google.com > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Put the ping in a loop or run the script with cron.
Instead of echoing you can send a notification.